# Starting "Network" under places at command line

Tags: ubuntu

I have Ubuntu 10.04. I would like to run at command line the gui application that I use for finding network places and navigate shared folders or network driver.
I mean the one located under menu PLACES->NETWORK.
I tried using "nautilus" but you need to know in advance which IP to give and this is not the case.
Is there this command line or should I really launch from the menu panel?

Answer (score 0):

Samba.  You'll need to learn how to use it, but once you master it, it is really handy.  [Here](http://www.stevens.edu/itwiki/w/index.php/Linux_Map_a_Network_Drive) is a brief tutorial. You can specify where a network share is mounted on your filesystem, options like username to use for mounting, etc.  You can even make shell scripts to mount shares that you use often.

I think you can even set up fstab to mount these network shares on boot, but I can't remember how to.

EDIT:

Here is a [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) on how to connect to a windows share permanently. I think linux shares are pretty similar.

Here is another [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/configure-a-system-to-automount-a-samba-share-with-etcfstab/) for regular Samba shares.